# inline .dat files loading into SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

Anyone knows how to perform inline loading into SQL server, I have DsGen software provided by TCP council, it generates data files have the extension .dat. Is there any mechanism to load these files directly to SQL database (during the generation period). I have done that using import/export wizard, but that is not inline loading.

Comment: Is the file locked in some sort of way during generation? Try to copy, read etc. the file while it is loading.

Comment: the generated files' extensions are .dat, in import/export wizard I had to change it into .txt then import each file individually, I'am looking for a way to import all files automatically once they being generated, or to be generated directly into the MSSQL database, can I do that with file .dat ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish your task, here are two of them.

1. You may use the BULK INSERT command to import them. Basically, what the import wizzard does is about the same, but it let's you select the various options using a nifty GUI.
2. You can save the DTS package when running through the wizzard, create a SQL Server Agent job and execute this job using the `sp_start_job` stored procedure.

I like the BULK INSERT as it it easier to implement. Just play arround with the options until you get what you want.

Comment: can I make the generator write tables directly into the sql server database. The software called dsgen, and it has commands like :
create table customer_address
(
    ca_address_sk             integer               not null,
   ....
);
 is there statement I can add to such code to write table directly into the database, without using bulk insert ?

Comment: usually `INSERT INTO customer_address (ca_address_sk,..) values(...)`. Can you configure DSGEN to do that? However, BULK INSERT is *very* fast.

Comment: again, this is the question, DSGen is written in C++, can I write code to do that and maybe use ADO.net to link them ?